# Submit no "admin" do wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Eu criei uma página personalizada no "admin" do wordpress que tem um campo de texto e um botão de envio. Preciso descobrir como fazer enviar a página para ser salva, mas não consiga encontrar nada na web. Alguém sabe a 'ação' precisa estar no formulário para conseguir fazer essa função?

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_menu_pages');

function my_menu_pages(){
    add_menu_page('My Page Title', 'Popup Segmentado', 'manage_options', 'popup-segmentado',  'fomulario_padrao', $icon_url = 'dashicons-forms', $position = null );
}

function fomulario_padrao(){ 
echo '<div class="_pop-gif" style="margin-left:20px;width:45%;">
  <form name="post" action="post.php" method="post" id="post">
   <p>
    <label for="nome_produto_popup">Nome do Produto</label>
    <input type="text" name="nome_produto_popup" id="nome_produto_popup" value="'.$values["nome_padrao_popup"][0].'" style="width:100%;"/>
   </p>
   <p>
    <label for="preco_produto_popup">Preço do Produto</label>
    <input type="text" name="preco_produto_popup" id="preco_produto_popup" value="'.$values["preco_padrao_popup"][0].'" style="width:100%;"/>
   </p>
   <p>
    <label for="imagem_produto_popup">Imagem do Produto</label>
    <input type="text" name="imagem_produto_popup" id="imagem_produto_popup" value="'.$values["imagem_padrao_popup"][0].'" style="width:100%;"/>
   </p>
   <p>
    <label for="imagem_produto_popup">Link do Produto</label>
    <input type="text" name="imagem_produto_popup" id="imagem_produto_popup" value="'.$values["link_padrao_popup"][0].'" style="width:100%;"/>
   </p>
   <p>
    '.submit_button().'
   </p>
  </form>
 </div>';
}
```

Comment: Não entendi direito como assim "enviar a página para ser salva"? Vc quer que quando clique em Enviar o cara salve o pagina.php no disco?

Comment: Não, seria para salvar o formulário dentro de um banco de dados ou algo parecido.